# viewer.spinOnce () failed normal_estimation_using_integral_images.cpp

Tags: c++, visualization

Testing **normal_estimation_using_integral_images.cpp**, result showed for a sec, but failed right away at line `viewer.spinOnce ();`:

```
    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
      viewer.spinOnce ();
    }
```

with the following **ERROR** message:

```
X connection to p% broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-ceuxubyq.vps" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-iriujkvs.ttm"
```

Can anybody please help?

Cheers